# How to call a function from the top level module function?

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

I'm Python noob and I want to develop a windows app with multiprocessing support. I have found an example here: http://zetcode.com/articles/tkinterlongruntask/. But now my problem is that, I can't update the scrollable text from the `generatePI` method which is a top level module function.

Could any of you guys give me a solution or point me to the right direction?

The complete code:

```
from tkinter import (Tk, BOTH, Text, E, W, S, N, END, 
NORMAL, DISABLED, StringVar)
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Label, Button, Progressbar, Entry
from tkinter import scrolledtext

from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, Queue
from queue import Empty
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext


DELAY1 = 80
DELAY2 = 20

# Queue must be global
q = Queue()

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, name="frame")   
             
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()
            
    
    def initUI(self):
  
        self.parent.title("Pi computation")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    
        self.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
    
        lbl1 = Label(self, text="Digits:")
        lbl1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=E, padx=10, pady=10)
    
        self.ent1 = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.ent1.insert(END, "4000")
        self.ent1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
    
        lbl2 = Label(self, text="Accuracy:")
        lbl2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.ent2 = Entry(self, width=10)
        self.ent2.insert(END, "100")
        self.ent2.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky=W)        
    
        self.startBtn = Button(self, text="Start", 
            command=self.onStart)
        self.startBtn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
    
        self.pbar = Progressbar(self, mode='indeterminate')        
        self.pbar.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky=W+E)     
    
        self.txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self)  
        self.txt.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=4, padx=10, pady=5,
        columnspan=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)
   
    
    def onStart(self):
    
        self.startBtn.config(state=DISABLED)
        self.txt.delete("1.0", END)
    
        digits = int(self.ent1.get())
        accuracy = int(self.ent2.get())
            
        self.p1 = Process(target=generatePi, args=(q, digits, accuracy))
        self.p1.start()
        self.pbar.start(DELAY2)
        self.after(DELAY1, self.onGetValue)
    
   
    def onGetValue(self):
    
        if (self.p1.is_alive()):
        
            self.after(DELAY1, self.onGetValue)
            return
        else:    
    
           try:

               self.txt.insert('end', q.get(0))
               self.txt.insert('end', "\n")
               self.pbar.stop()
               self.startBtn.config(state=NORMAL)

           except Empty:
               print("queue is empty")
        
# Generate function must be a top-level module funtion            
def generatePi(q, digs, acc):

   getcontext().prec = digs

   pi = Decimal(0)
   k = 0
   n = acc
    
   while k < n:
        pi += (Decimal(1)/(16**k))*((Decimal(4)/(8*k+1)) - \
            (Decimal(2)/(8*k+4)) - (Decimal(1)/(8*k+5))- \
            (Decimal(1)/(8*k+6)))
        k += 1

   q.put(pi)


def main():  

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("400x350+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PS: credit to [zetcode.com](https://zetcode.com)

Comment: you could always include ```self``` as the first argument in your Process line.  i.e. ```self.p1 = Process(target=generatePi, args=(self, q, digits, accuracy))```  then change generatePi's argument list accordingly

Comment: I have did that, but got error
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: You already try to update the `scrolledtext` inside `onGetValue()` but the logic is incorrect: `if self.p1.is_alive()` is true if the process is still running, so the `else` block will not be executed.  Think carefully again the required logic.

Comment: The above code is what I'm referring to implement something. If I change the `generatePi()` function to something else like updating a database table or so. And I want to show the status in the scrollable text like 'updating row 1', 'updating row 2', .. etc. In that case, I have to call the `self.txt.insert()` from `generatePi()`.